# Exibir Resultado de Simulação em outra pagina

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

Tenho um formulario que recebe dados do cliente interessado em adquirir um emprestimo, quando ele clica em simular o programa faz a simulação e grava no banco de dados, até ai funciona bem. Porem preciso exibir os detalhes desta simulação em outra pagina. ja tentei fazer o redirecionamento com o `"return RedirectToAction("Details", idsimulacao);"` porém não obtive sucesso...

Segue codigo:

Create:

```
[HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("Id,Nome,Cpf,ValorDesejado,ValorParcela,Telefone,ConvenioID,ProdutoID,DataSimulacao,ContratacaoID,Dispensada,Rg,Endereco,Numero,Bairro,Cep,Agencia,Conta,TipoConta,UrlDocFrente,UrlDocVerso,UrlSelfie")] Simulacao simulacao)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            _context.Add(simulacao);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            CalcularValorParcela(simulacao.Id, simulacao.ProdutoID, simulacao);
            idsimulacao = simulacao.Id;
           _context.Update(simulacao);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return RedirectToAction("Details", idsimulacao);

        }
        ViewData["ConvenioID"] = new SelectList(_context.Convenio, "Id", "Nome", simulacao.ConvenioID);
        ViewData["ProdutoID"] = new SelectList(_context.Produtos, "Id", "Nome", simulacao.ProdutoID);
        return RedirectToAction("Details", idsimulacao);

    }
```

Details

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Details(int id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        var simulacao = await _context.Simulacao
            .Include(s => s.Convenio)
            .Include(s => s.Produto)
            .FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.Id == id);
        if (simulacao == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        return View();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Tenta usar esse comando aqui

```
return RedirectToAction("Details", new { id = idsimulacao });
```

Comment: O Método RedirectToAction não retornou nada, então passei a usar o método: `RedirectToRoute(new { controller = "Simulacaos", action = "Details", id = simulacao.Id });` e ele retornou o era necessário.